# Customize Android AChartEngine PieChart (show text inside chart)

Tags: android, achartengine

Is there a way to update the text inside a Pie Chart (generated through the achartEngine API). I want to show the percentage there. In the picture below, I have it updated manually (i.e. 60%, 30% and 10%) to show you.

[image: Image1]

I could not find relevant method in the SimpleSeriesRenderer class. Here is the code I am using.

```
CategorySeries categorySeries = new CategorySeries("Chart");

for (int i = 0; i < series.size(); i++) {
    categorySeries.add(series.get(i), series_data.get(i));
}

DefaultRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();

defaultRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
defaultRenderer.setShowLabels(true);
defaultRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
defaultRenderer.setShowTickMarks(true);
defaultRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(40f);
defaultRenderer.setLegendTextSize(40f);
defaultRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);

for (int i = 0; i < series_data.size(); i++) {

    SimpleSeriesRenderer simpleSeriesRenderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    simpleSeriesRenderer.setColor(  chartColor[i]);
    defaultRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(simpleSeriesRenderer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom class, which extends `PieChart` and override it's `drawLabel()` (and may be `draw()`) method:

```
public class AdvancedPieChart extends PieChart {

   @Override
   protected void drawLabel(Canvas canvas, String labelText, DefaultRenderer renderer, List<RectF> prevLabelsBounds, int centerX, int centerY, float shortRadius, float longRadius, float currentAngle, float angle, int left, int right, int color, Paint paint, boolean line, boolean display) {
      // do what You want with Label text, e.g. just
      canvas.drawText(labelText, xLabel, yLabel, paint);
   }

}
```

and use your `AdvancedPieChart` class instead of "standard" `PieChart`.

***Update:***

For example, this implementation:

```
public class AdvancedPieChart extends PieChart {

    public AdvancedPieChart(CategorySeries dataset, DefaultRenderer renderer) {
        super(dataset, renderer);
    }


    @Override
    protected void drawLabel(Canvas canvas, String labelText, DefaultRenderer renderer, List<RectF> prevLabelsBounds, int centerX, int centerY, float shortRadius, float longRadius, float currentAngle, float angle, int left, int right, int color, Paint paint, boolean line, boolean display) {
        super.drawLabel(canvas, labelText, renderer, prevLabelsBounds, centerX, centerY, shortRadius, longRadius, currentAngle, angle, left, right, color, paint, line, display);

        String additionalText = "Hello";
        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaint.setTextSize(18 * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / 160f);
        textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(additionalText, 0, additionalText.length(), bounds);
        canvas.drawText(additionalText, this.mCenterX - bounds.width() / 2, this.mCenterY - bounds.height() / 3, textPaint);
    }
}
```

draw text "Hello" in the center of chart:

[image: AdvancedPieChart screenshot]

Layout (`activity_main.xml`) for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ua.com.omelchenko.chartapplication.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

(of course You don't need nested layouts)

and `MainActivity.java` is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout mPieChartHolder;
    private GraphicalView mChartView;
    private PieChart mPieChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] names = new String[] { "Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3" };
        double[] values = { 20, 30, 50 };
        int[] colors = { Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE };

        CategorySeries categorySeries = new CategorySeries("Pie Chart");
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            categorySeries.add(names[i], values[i]);
        }

        DefaultRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
            seriesRenderer.setColor(colors[i]);
            defaultRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            defaultRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(20f);
            defaultRenderer.setLegendTextSize(20f);
            defaultRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
            defaultRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
        }

        mPieChart = new AdvancedPieChart(categorySeries, defaultRenderer);
        mChartView = new GraphicalView(this, mPieChart);

        mPieChartHolder = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_holder);
        mPieChartHolder.addView(mChartView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

}
```

(of course it's just demo).

And if You press `Ctrl+LeftMouseButton` when mouse pointer is on `PieChart` word in AndroidStudio 2.0 and above You can find many interesting things about inner organization of `PieChart`, for example coordinates of pies centers etc.

Comment: Thanks, but labels are already appearing in this chart A:AA, B:BB & C:CC. I want to keep them, but additionally want to show text inside chart..Is it possible with your approach ?   Still this a good pointer, I will  check , if something is available with custom class.

Comment: Just add what You need e.g.: `canvas.drawText("My text", 100, 200, newPaint);` - You can change everything in `drawLabel()` and `draw()` methods.